# V+, V- and GND - Getting started with virtual grounds

Tags: digital-logic, analog, voltage-divider, virtual-ground

I've been happily playing around with TTL logic but have recently come across an Analog / Digital converter [TSC7106](http://bg-electronics.de/datenblaetter/Schaltkreise/TSC7106.pdf) whilst tearing apart an old thermostat which has demanded V+, GND and ... V- :o

I see that I should come up with some kind of virtual ground but I'm unsure of the simplest approach. I've tried setting up my bench power supply to 10v and then creating a 50/50 voltage divider with 10K resistors but I notice that any asymmetric load seems to heavily reduce the voltage on the loaded side.

I have a fair range of resistors, capacitors and have a couple of operational amplifiers that I can salvage from various junk (TL081CP, MC1458P1, PMIOP07CP). Could someone point me towards the easiest solution to get this A/D converter up and running?

Cheers,

Andrew

P.S. I'm an IT engineer that's just getting started with electronics.

[image: Test circuit diagram]

Comment: take a look at the answers to this question http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/219827/using-12v-dc-to-create-symmetric-power-source/219830

Comment: Try 220 ohm resistor in series with 1N756 zener (its 5.2 volts, at 10mA, if I recall correctly). The current, nearly 25 ma, from the resistor, gives you some control over the virtual_ground.

Comment: Also interesting: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/46916/op-amps-where-to-split-the-rail